# Questions regarding Going Live with PayPal

Tags: paypal, live

Im trying to get live with my webshop and do the steps necessary. I tried to ask the same question in the merchant support but it have taken over 10 days for them not to respond so I try here instead.

It says in the Going live Checklist:
**- Make sure your PayPal API calls are directed at PayPal's production environment.**
So where am I gonna put this https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp ? 
In the code where the buttons are created or in the PDT which is called? Those are the only placces I can think of that would do any difference

It also says:
**- Get your live API credentials and use them wherever you call PayPal API operations.**
I have generated them but where to use them? In my PDT which I redirect my customers to after a purchase or in the buttons?
Should the https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp ? be somewhere there as well?

**A final question. Do I have to "register" my "app" too? I tried to read but didnt understand. I have a website which Im gonna use your buttons in. Do I need to register that as well? How do I do this?**

This is some of my pdt.php-code:

```
<?php

/*
update: 06/27/2011
- updated to use cURL for better security, assumes PHP version 5.3
*/

// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'

$req = 'cmd=_notify-synch';

$tx_token = $_GET['tx'];

$pp_hostname = "www.sandbox.paypal.com"; 

// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-synch';

$tx_token = $_GET['tx'];
$auth_token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
// real xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
$req .= "&tx=$tx_token&at=$auth_token";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://$pp_hostname/cgi-bin/webscr");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
//set cacert.pem verisign certificate path in curl using 'CURLOPT_CAINFO' field here,
//if your server does not bundled with default verisign certificates.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Host: $pp_hostname"));
$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at a checklist for going live with PayPal API calls -- you're using PayPal buttons, so you don't need to worry about that.

For you, the only things you need to change are:
- The $pp_hostname for your PDT script
- The $pp_hostname for your IPN script (if you use it)
- The "action" part of your button  (from https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr to https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr)

Comment: Thanks Robert really! Ive tried to contact Merc Supp for over 10 days without answer. So, thats it?! Then im already done. One more thing tho: in my pdt I will use if statements to see if the added items in the cart (after a purchase, and redirected to pdt.php)matches up and if so I will display downloadable content. Only, this cant be tested. Ican set up sandbox buttons and with id 1, 2, 3, 4 to see if those are working correctly and then witch to live. But when I do im not 100% sure that those are working, since I have much more items and item_numers than just 4.

Comment: And to create that many buttons in the Sandbox would be too much of a waste of time. Do you understand what I mean, only way to test live is to make a real card purchase and see what they got when redirected? One last thing, since I were looking on the wrong place, I dont have to register the product either?

Comment: That's right - you don't need to register your app either. Can you share your Merchant Tech Support ticket number with me? I'll just make sure that gets closed for you.

Comment: Regarding the testing you could dynamically pass the item number, rather than creating a new button for each. That way it shouldn't be a problem at all to test it in Sandbox.

Comment: Ok, thats good news. The reference number is: 130303-000040 thats what u needed? Also im not quite sure how you mean I could dynamically pass the item number. Are there any links and information regarding that I can read up on? Lets say I would make a fake purchase containing 10 products, where 8 of them are products that will trigger the display of downloadable content. I know how to write this in the pdt, but how do you mean with the button/buttons? Can I do this from sandbox.paypal.com?